# SQL DateKey to normal Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL DateKey that looks like this

```
YYYYMMDD
```

This was created using

```
Convert(varchar,[ModifiedOn],112))
```

However I want this field in a view to display the normal dateformat in the UK as DD-MM-YYYY

how can I do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Its a varchar(10)

Comment: Why don't you use the modifiedOn column directly instead of using an intermediate format?

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

Just try `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(YourStringDate AS DATE),105)`

As the date-value `YYYYMMDD` seems to be a string in the so called *unseparated format* (and not a `BIGINT`), SQL-Server will cast this string to `DATE` implicitly. `CONVERT` together with 105 will format this the way you want it.

Starting with SQL Server 2012 there is `FORMAT()`. You might use this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(YourStringDate AS DATE),'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

One method dispenses with the date stuff and just uses string arithmetic:

```
select (right(ModifiedOn, 2) + '-' +
        substring(ModifiedOn, 3, 2) + '-' +
        left(ModifiedOn, 4)
       ) as mmddyyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a [date table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) to your database.

Date tables can provide a handy selection of pre-calculated formats, for you to switch between.

They are also useful aggregation targets (`GROUP BY DATENAME(QUARTER, CAST(DateKey AS DATE))` Vs `GROUP BY DimDate.[Quater]`).

```
-- Basic date table.
CREATE TABLE DimDate
    (
        DateKey         INT         PRIMARY KEY,
        [Date]          DATE        NOT NULL,
        [Year]          INT         NOT NULL,
        [Quater]        VARCHAR(2)  NOT NULL,
        [DD_MM_YYYY]    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    )
;
```

Contains:

```
DateKey     [Date]      [Year]  [Quater]    [DD_MM_YYYY]
--------------------------------------------------------
20160101    2016-01-01  2016    Q1          01-01-2016
20160102    2016-01-02  2016    Q1          02-01-2016
...
20161231    2016-12-31  2016    Q4          31-12-2016
```

There is an argument against formatting within the database.  Proponants will tell you that formatting is a cosmetic operation, best performed in the presentation layer.  Your database, they say, should store only the cold hard facts.  Personally I'm not so sure.  I agree SQL isn't the best langaue to use for formatting, but sometimes it is the only language in play.